# Postgres SQL command to figure out what all columns can be enums but aren't?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

The context is that I'm building a generic tool that can take in different customer databases and connect it with an internal dashboard. So in my use case, I'm frequently running into dozens of varchar/int columns that are honestly just enums.

I'm looking for a way so that I don't have to manually sift through each column and see if it can be an enum.

Is there a command that can automatically detect enum-able columns in a table

`SQL: Select <column_name> FROM <table> WHERE <column_name> has maximum 10 distinct values`

Or something else like the above. Any ideas?

Comment: I advise you **not** to do that. Enums are only good if you never need to remove a value (you cannot do that with enums), and to determine if that is feasible requires understanding the data. Any automatic procedure is misguided. Use a lookup table or a check constraint to limit the available entries in a more flexible manner.

Comment: Please rest assured I am well aware of what I am doing, it's implication and have come to the conclusion that it makes sense in my situation. I am wrangling with ~80+ tables with 100+ columns each and am simply looking for a way to be reassured that I have the right data types (this is part of a dev setup process, obviously I wouldn't set something like this loose in prod).

Answer (score 1):

You can use pg_stats statistics system catalog to have an *estimation* of distinct values for a given column in a given table:

```
select schemaname, tablename, attname, n_distinct
from pg_stats 
where n_distinct > 0 and n_distinct <= 10;
```

But it is only an **estimation.**

Note that for n_distinct column:

> If greater than zero, the estimated number of distinct values in the
>   column. If less than zero, the negative of the number of distinct
>   values divided by the number of rows. (The negated form is used when
>   ANALYZE believes that the number of distinct values is likely to
>   increase as the table grows; the positive form is used when the column
>   seems to have a fixed number of possible values.) For example, -1
>   indicates a unique column in which the number of distinct values is
>   the same as the number of rows.